# How to transform ordinal categorical income into a continuous variable?

Tags: r, data-transformation, ordinal-data, continuous-data

I have a large data set including an ordinal categorical income variable and want to transform this variable into a continuous variable. I want to perform a simulation study with the dataset and therefore need a continuous income variable. For my analysis I am using R.

Here are some test data, if needed:

```
set.seed(123)

N <- 1000
y <- sample(1:3, N, replace = TRUE, prob = c(1, 7, 3))

x1 <- rnorm(N)
x2 <- runif(N)

x1_noise <- x1 + rnorm(N, 0, 1)
x2_noise <- x2 + rnorm(N, 0, 1.5)

# Test data
data <- data.frame(y = sort(y),
               x1 = x1[order(x1_noise)],
               x2 = x2[order(x2_noise)])

# Category 1 has a range of 0-1000 EURO.
# Category 2 has a range of 1000-3000 EURO.
# Category 3 has a range of 3000 EURO and higher.
```

What is the best way for such a transformation? Is it possible to do this with imputation methods?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to transform an ordinal categorical variable to a continuous one ?
This kind of preprocessing depends on what you have in mind for the sequence.

Comment: I want to do a monte carlo simulation study, in which Im going to test several imputation methods. The dataset with the ordinal income variable will be used as population for the simulation study. I need to transform the original ordinal variable, since I want to test the performance of the imputation methods with a continuous variable.

Comment: Your variable isn't only ordered, it is "censored", see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35634940/dealing-with-less-thans-in-r/35647538#35647538  You'll need to define "performance of the imputation method", it seems hard to get performance better than assigning the correct category.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I read your other post and found your post and the discussion in the thread very helpful. Right now I am planning to do the following: step 1) take a continuous income distribution of a similar study; step 2) categorize this income variable like in my dataset; step 3) draw for each category randomly from the continuous income variable. With this procedure I will try to rebuild the real income distribution

Comment: The variable is binned (and censored), not ordinal. I even wouldn't maybe call it "categorical" at all. Because you _know_ the real ranges of income corresponding to each of its level.

Comment: Good point, I agree that the description "ordinal categorical" is flawed in this case. Do you think there are any downsides of the 3 steps, which I described in my former comment? I just need to transform this binned income variable as realistically as possible into a continuous variable.